# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in maven/IntelliJ project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project that fails at runtime with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. The module I'm trying to run, call it A, depends on module B which depends on C which contains the missing file.

The symptoms: The exact same module runs fine on another computer. I know the code on both computers is the same as they both checked out a copy from the same git repo. So the only files that could be different are the ones in `.gitignore`, e.g. `.lst`, `.idea/`. I don't think it's a version conflict since both computers contain the same version of module C in the local maven repo.

The only clue I have is that module C is on the classpath when I run it on the working computer, and missing in the one that it's not. I don't know why that is since the `target/.classpath.user` files on both computers are identical as far as I can tell.

I tried deleting the local maven repo, invalidating caches on IntelliJ and rebuilding the project, didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Delete all .idea,.iml files and import it again

Comment: I am working with NetBeans, so I am not sure if this is relevant to IntelliJ, but in a Netbeans you can see for each Maven project which JAR dependencies are actually on the class path.  I assume IntelliJ has the same functionality, to be confirmed by an other IntelliJ user.

Comment: Have you visually checked the class is in the C JAR in your local Maven repository?  Does the C module have a release version or snapshot version?

Comment: @toongeorges, yes I have and it exists. It's a snapshot.

Comment: Ended up going nuclear, as suggested by @rathna. Works now.